# Scala image resize and crop

Tags: java, scala, image-processing, playframework-2.2

I have a Play framework 2.2 app and I want to resize and crop images (like profile picture). Is there a good Scala library that I can use to do this? And if not which Java library should I use (considering performance, quality...). An example would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm using ImageMagick, I'm running from my play app as an external program, it's written in C, when it comes to quality and performance is one of the best.

Answer (score 3):

I've used Thumbnaiator https://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/ in Java before. Works really well and is pure Java so doesn't require any native dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to resize images, you don't need any addition library/dependencies. Just use the Java `BufferedImage` class so be enough.

```
// Target size
val width = 100
val height = 100

// Load image from disk
val originalImage: BufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("test-data/test.jpg"))

// Resize
val resized = originalImage.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)

// Saving Image back to disck
val bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
bufferedImage.getGraphics.drawImage(resized, 0, 0, null)
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "JPEG", new File("test-data/resized.jpg"))
```

You'll need these imports:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import java.io.File
import javax.imageio.ImageIO
```